# How to MapRoute? If http://abc.com/Home go to Home Controller else go to Misc Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have three controllers, `Home`, `Blog` and `Misc`.

When I type `mydomain.com/Home` at the address bar, the browser displays the view for the home controller.

When I type `mydomain.com/Blog` at the address bar, the browser displays the view for blog controller.

And when I type `mydomain.com/anything` (not `Home` nor `Blog`) the browser displays the view for the misc controller.

How to map route for above?

I mean that when type something other than /Home or /Blog 
for example /Test,  /Book,  /Book/Index,  /xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa,  /etc/etc/etc,
then my Misc Controller will be launched

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default",
"{controller}/{action}/{id}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);


routes.MapRoute(
     "Misc",
     "{*id}",
      new { controller = "Misc", action = "Index", id = "" },
;
```

Comment: Can you **show us** your routes??? How you define them in code??? And what exactly do you want to achieve when you type something other than /Home or /Blog ??

Answer (score 0):

In order to trap the 'other' entries, you need to override the controller factory that determines which controller to use:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    try
    {
        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }

    catch (HttpException ex)
    {
        int httpCode = ex.GetHttpCode();
        if(httpCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            IController controller = new MiscController();
            ((MiscController)controller).DefaultAction(); // whatever action you want to invoke
            return controller;
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register this controller factory in the Global.asax startup.